AnimatedVisibility reversed animation issue
I encountered a problem that if there is AnimatedVisibility and the state changes immediately from true to false (in time when the animation is played), then the animation is reversed. I
Googled, used GPT 4, didn’t find anything useful and also couldn’t find it in the official documentation
AnimatedVisibility(visible = ignoreAnimState == - 1,
              enter = EnterTransition.None,
              exit = if (dismissAnimStateCancel) ExitTransition.None else exitLeftAnim
          ) {
              println("We have entered the null state ${dismissAnimState}")
              content()
          }


